# Why use Context with mako?

Tags: python, mako

I reads manual by Makotemplate and see follows code:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.runtime import Context
from StringIO import StringIO

mytemplate = Template("hello, ${name}!")
buf = StringIO()
ctx = Context(buf, name="jack")
mytemplate.render_context(ctx)
print buf.getvalue()
```

What profit use Context?

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't use it directly, it contains both the output buffer and a dictionary of variables that can be referenced from within the template. It's usually preferable to use the `render` method of `Template`.

```
>>> Template('hello ${name}!').render(name='jack')
<<< u'hello jack!'
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/runtime.html#context).